# Why is one button overriding my other button even with unique classes?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am new to javascript/jquery and have been stuck on this problem for a while. So I have two buttons, a clear button that will clear all forms in a row of a table and a reset button that holds all initial values for each row of the table.

**The issue:** So currently when I run the script the reset button will keep overriding the clear button. Meaning when I click on clear it will also act as a reset instead of clearing the row. I tried creating unique classes (.clear_button, .reset_button) to be called as you see here. I find it hard to troubleshoot javascript especially being new to it so why is this happening?

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".clear_button").click(function(){
    function my_clearFunction(i) {
        document.getElementById("id_form-" + (i - 1) + "-Name").value = " ";
        document.getElementById("id_form-" + (i - 1) + "-Start").value = "";
        document.getElementById("id_form-" + (i - 1) + "-End").value = "";
        document.getElementById("id_form-" + (i - 1) + "-Advanced").value = " ";
    }
  });
  $(".reset_button").ready(function(){
    $('#reset :input:not([type="button"])').each(function(idx, ele) {
      ele.dataset.initvalue = ele.value;
    });
    $('#reset [type="button"]').on('click', function(e) {
      // reset current row............
      $(this).closest('tr').find(':input:not([type="button"])').each(function(idx, ele) {
          // restore the initial value
          ele.value = ele.dataset.initvalue;
      })
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

**Note**: I understand the code is not uniform, for example, my clear button logic was not written in jquery. Sorry I couldn't attach a jsfiddle, this project is relatively pretty big and I use django to import my forms so it was difficult to set up. So any input would be greatly appreciated since I have been stuck on this for quite some time and can't seem to get it. It's also worth mentioning my input tags for the buttons so here they are.

```
<input type="button"  class="clear_button" onclick="my_clearFunction({{ forloop.counter }})" value="  x  ">
                    
<input  type="button" class="reset_button" value="  x  ">
```

Comment: Your `click` handler for the clear button doesn't clear anything. All it does is define a local function that it never calls.

Comment: You can't call `my_clearfunction()` from `onclick` because that only looks for names in the global scope, and the function is local to the click handler callback function.

Comment: If you're not getting an "undefined function" error when you click on the clear button, you must have another definition for `my_clearfunction()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I click on clear it will also act as a reset instead of clearing the row.

Your reset listener is declared as

```
$('#reset [type="button"]').on('click', function(e) {
  ...
})
```

It seems the `#reset` element contains both clear and reset buttons, so clicking in either will restore the initial values.

The clear button, also, has two handlers of its own. There is one declared in code which in turn declares a function (that isn't called in the handler itself) and an inline handler that tries to invoke said function. That shouldn't work, for it isn't visible from the global scope.

Instead of

```
$(button).on('click',(e)=>{
  function doSomethingWith(i) {
   ...
  }
  doSomethingWith(e.target.id);
})
```

If should be

```
function doSomethingWith(i) {
   ...
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   $(button).on('click',(e)=>{
     doSomethingWith(e.target.id);
   });
});
```

then it  would be visible for the handler but also on the global scope, so you *could* call it using the inline "onclick"

```
 <button onclick="doSomethingWith({{ forloop.counter }})" >
```

However, you shouldn't have an inline handler if you're also declaring one in JS. Since you're dealing with the reset button *in code*, stick to that approach for the clear button too.

---

Now, the approach you follow to clear a row needs for you to know the row relative index, and the inputs on each row, for which you compute their respective ids. Whereas, when it comes to reset the original values, you don't need to know anything:

```
$('.reset_button').on('click', function(e) {
  // reset current row............
  $(this).closest('tr').find(':input:not([type="button"])').each(function(idx, ele) {
      // restore the initial value
      ele.value = ele.dataset.initvalue;
  })
});
```

The button needs only know it's inside the same `<tr>` element as other inputs whose value needs to be restored. **It doesn't care about the index, the IDs, not even what inputs are in place, as long as they aren't buttons**.

You should do the same to clear the values:

```
$('.clear_button').on('click', function(e) {
  // reset current row............
  $(this).closest('tr').find(':input:not([type="button"])').each(function(idx, ele) {
      ele.value =  "";
  });
});
```

---

When it comes to storing the original value I'm also used to resort to  [jQuery.data](https://api.jquery.com/data/) . Anyway, for this use case you can perfectly stick to

```
input.dataset.initialValue = input.value
```

Instead of

```
$(input).data('initialValue',input.value)
```

As long as you keep in mind these approaches **are not interchangeable**. You can't set the initialValue with dataset then get it with jQuery.data or the other way around.

```js
function randomTime() {
  return [
    Number(100 * Math.random() % 12).toFixed(0).padStart(2, '0'),
    Number(100 * Math.random() % 60).toFixed(0).padStart(2, '0')
  ].join(':');
}

function addFormRow(player_name = 'N/A') {
  let tr = $('<tr class="form_row">'),
    name = $('<input type="text" name="name" class="name">'),
    start = $('<input type="time" name="start" class="start">'),
    end = $('<input type="time" name="end" class="end">'),
    advanced = $('<input type="number" name="advanced" class="advanced">'),
    clear = $('<button class="clear_button">Clear</button>'),
    reset = $('<button class="reset_button">Reset</button>');

  name.val(player_name);
  start.val(randomTime());
  advanced.val(parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10))
  end.val(randomTime());

  for (let input of [name, start, end, advanced, clear, reset]) {
    $('<td>').append(input).appendTo(tr);
   }

  tr.appendTo('#forms tbody');

}
addFormRow('player one');
addFormRow('player two');
addFormRow('player three');

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#forms tbody tr').each((index,tr)=>{
    $(tr).find('input').each((idx,input)=>{
       $(input).data('initialValue',$(input).val());
    });
  })
  $(".clear_button").on('click', (e) => {
    let $this = $(e.target),
      tr = $this.closest('tr');
    tr.find('input').each((index, input) => {
      input.value = '';
    });
  });
  $(".reset_button").on('click', (e) => {
    let $this = $(e.target),
      tr = $this.closest('tr');
    tr.find('input').each((index, input) => {
      $(input).val($(input).data('initialValue'));
    });
  });

});
```

```css
.advanced {
  width: 4em;
}

.name {
  width: 9em;
}

.start,
.end {
  width: 5.5em;
}

.form_row input {
  height: 1.1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="forms">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>start</th>
      <th>end</th>
      <th>advance</th>
      <th colspan="2">actions</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If only I can upvote more than once! Thank you for all this useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$(".clear_button").click()` handler isn't doing anything. It defines a local function, but never calls it.

Instead of trying to call the function from `onclick()`, add a `data` attribute to buttons holding the index. Then the click handler can get this attribute and use it to find all the related elements that it needs to clear.

```js
$(".clear_button").click(function() {
  var i = $(this).data("rel-id");
  document.getElementById("id_form-" + (i - 1) + "-Name").value = " ";
  document.getElementById("id_form-" + (i - 1) + "-Start").value = "";
  document.getElementById("id_form-" + (i - 1) + "-End").value = "";
  document.getElementById("id_form-" + (i - 1) + "-Advanced").value = " ";
});
```

```html
<input type="button"  class="clear_button" data-rel-id="{{ forloop.counter }}" value="  x  ">
```

Comment: I did not know about the data attribute, thank you for the helpful insight! I do realize why onclick() was affecting the script, but now that I included the data attribute it still does not work and the reset continues to override the clear button.